# Is it feasible to get a remote job in Web Development with what experience I have?

Tags: telecommute

I am 23 years old and I live in Alaska. I was recently laid off from the Oil and Gas industry and began to look outwards for new career paths. My wife has a child from her previous relationship so leaving state is not an option. College is not an option due to my financial situation. Trust me. It is not an option, I've looked...hard...please don't say "go to school".

I have some light web development experience but nothing major. I was looking at trying to find a job in the field but find 99% of the jobs want previous experience. I have been taking classes on codecademy anf started to expand my skills. I am in the process of building a website but I clearly have a lot to learn. I pretty much have a grasp on HTML, CSS/Bootstrap, JQuery, and am picking up on wordpress. Would I be better off trying to come up with 15K+ to go to a coding bootcamp? Or try to keep building small websites? My problem is soon I will have to start bringing in some kind of income (on work comp right now due to a knee Injury, but that will likely end soon). And I don't know if I can get a decent portfolio up in time. Is this a feasible endeavor? Will a small handful of websites be enough to convince someone of remote work?

Yes I know this is similar to another ques to on but IT and Web dev are different and people from Web Dev have different insights on it than people from IT. I realise they are similar but I feel it warrants a seperate question since they are both (hopefully) viable passions of mine
 Web dev more so.

Comment: Exact duplicate of your previous question.

Comment: No. The previous question is about being IT. This is about web development. They are both serious interests of mine that I am pursuing. IT appears to be unfeasible at this juncture in my life. Web Development may still be and is basically my last hope before I am forced back to the oilfield.

Comment: They may be similar in wording but the answers to them are vastly different

Comment: The fundamental question here is "Is it feasible to get a remote job in technology with little experience." The answer involves some kind of training/learning and job searches for that technology, regardless of the specific technology. In the context of all 12K questions on The Workplace, this would be considered a duplicate.

Comment: Look at the smaller underlying questions....

Comment: If you want folks to look at the smaller questions, rewrite to specifically ask only those questions.

Comment: @Weber This site (and the other Stack Exchange Q&A sites) are designed to be more helpful to you when you ask a single, targeted question that people can focus their answers on. When you ask many sub-questions, those tend to get overlooked.

Comment: I see. Constructive help such as that is appreciated instead instead of negative reception and down votes (which restricts me from posting now)

Comment: take a look on what it is asked on technologies, currently lot of sites are using framework that superset jQUery (angular for instance). Look what job offer you have in your state and learn the technologies accordingly.

Comment: @Weber Your questions aren't just similar in wording, they're exact copies save for one or two phrases. You got a negative reception because you simply copied your original question with some minor changes at the end. I downvote and flag those kinds of posts because in almost all cases they happen because a new user couldn't find his original post, doesn't have his original session/username to edit the original post or, worst case, is trying to dodge the close votes and downvotes that his original post go instead of improving the question.

Answer (score 3):

Do not waste time and money going to school to learn how to make web sites.

Visit [webmasters stack exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) and absorb as much as you can. Then ask the frequent posters there for the best learning resources. Find out how they got started.

I would be surprised if anyone there tells you to attend a formal tech school. Current web site technology is disastrously chaotic at its core. You will need to deal with unfinished standards, conflicting protocols, and buggy libraries. Nobody can teach you how to do that.

You can also apply to job postings that require experience. A few of those will be willing to hire you, perhaps at a reduced rate.

Some web developers start with a little *pro bono* work for a charity organization. Just be sure it's highly visible and well done, so you can point to it as part of your portfolio.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is the kind of advice I am looking for.

Answer (score -1):

$15K for a coding boot camp is not a good return. There are good books and free tutorials on the Internet.  Even not getting a degree junior college classes are typically economical.

On the low end people can build their own web sites.

On the mid and higher end they are gong to want experience.

Comment: I don't understand how it isn't a good return. Can you please explain?

Comment: $15K is a lot of money and they typically go at a fast pace.   And it does not mean much on a resume.

Comment: I didnt. The other question is about IT. This is about web dev. Very different paths

Comment: @Weber Not very different questions.  VTC.

Comment: Vtc? And I feel they have very different answers though the wording is close to the same.

Comment: Feel what you want.

Comment: @Weber Aniway, don't go to a bootcamp on specific technologies without having already taking a good grasp on them, or you may not being able to follow properly and absorb enough knowledge during the little time (yes one week is really short) it last.